# Different Yum results on two servers

Tags: centos, yum

Got some weird stuff going on in here:

- same OS
- same arch
- same yum repos
- `yum clean all` ran on both servers

Even after all of the above; the following command reveals two entirely different set of results:

```
[root@BE5 ~]# yum search spl-types --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=webtatic
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Warning: No matches found for: spl-types
No Matches found`

[root@BE4 /]# yum search spl-types --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=webtatic
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
php-pecl-spl-types.x86_64 : Standard PHP Library, Types Addon`
```

Any clues chaps?

Comment: Can you confirm that the repo config files are exactly the same on both servers? Is it possible the target URL is behind an lb with more than one real servers, and one server has the packages and the other one does not?

Comment: Potentially. The repo is the webtatic repo, and exactly the same, as I have provisioned it through puppet. I've MD5'd both files to be certain, and they're exactly the same strings :(

Comment: You mean `/etc/yum.conf` and contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/` are the same on both the servers?

Comment: yeah - Both `/etc/yum.conf` and both `/etc/yum.repo.d/` files have the the same MD5. EDIT: sorry I think you meant between servers, so yeah. the conf and repo.d files are different, but between the servers, they are identical.

Comment: @TimP Try giving the star (*) in single quotes. There should be a space before the next command-line parameter.

Comment: @pdp - my bad. that was a typo. Editted.